# How to assign new value if you setting the setter private in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new in kotlin and not able to understand how the getter and setter behave in kotlin, so if I set the setter to private. Then what is the way of updating the value.

```
package foo

class Person() {
var name: String = "defaultValue"
   private set

}
```

Comment: May I ask you why do you make your setter private, is there any reason?

Answer (score 6):

If you set your setter to be private, then this setter will be accessible only from within its class. In other words you can use normal assignment even when your setter is private but only from within the class.

```
class Person() {
    var name: String = "defaultValue"
        private set

    fun foo(bar: String) {
        name = bar // name can be set here
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Person().name = "foo" // error. Name can be accessed but can not be modified here as its setter is private.
}
```

For more information check the Kotlin's [Visibility documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

the kotlin code above will be transform to java code by kotlin compiler more like as below:

```
package foo;
public final class Person{
  private String name = "defaultValue";

  public final String getName(){ 
      return name;
  }

  private final void setName(String name){
     this.name=name;
  }
}
```

which means you can only change the `name` field in the `Person` class. another situation is if you want to modify the `name` property with *private* setter out of the `Person` class. you can using java reflection instead, for example:

```
val person = Person();

val field = Person::name.javaField!!.apply { isAccessible = true }
field.set(person, "bob")
println(person.name)// "bob"

val setter = Person::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String::class.java)!!
                               .apply {
                                   isAccessible = true
                               }
setter.invoke(person, "john")
println(person.name)// "john"
```